# ArgumentOutOfRangeException at passing text from textbox ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an ERROR Says:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length

At Code:

```
         string charstr = fun.getCustChar(txtNewCustName.Text);// ERROR line
         string cmdStr = fun.select("CustomerId", "SD_Cust_master",* and So on...*
         SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
```

How so resolve this?

Comment: What's the implementation of `fun.getCustChar()`?

Comment: There must a SubString function used inside the fun.getCustChar() function. that line is giving the actual error.